# How to change a row data with a single query with soft delete method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am using [Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting) method to delete data from my table :

```
$q = Company::findOrFail(1);
$q->delete();
```

This woks fine, but before delete I want to change a row column value `status = 1` to `status = 0`, but it's not working with eloquent `delete()` method :

```
$q = Company::findOrFail(1);
$q->status = '0';
$q->delete();
```

But it's working fine if I use **two** separate query :

```
$q = Company::findOrFail(1);
$q->status = '0';
$q->save();

$q = Company::findOrFail(1);
$q->delete();
```

How can I achieve this with **one** eloquent query?

Answer (score 1):

You must save your changes on the company model like below :

```
$q = Company::findOrFail(1);
$q->status = 0;
$q->save();
$q->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
$q = Company::findOrFail(1);
$q->status = 0;
$q->save();
$q->delete();
```

or

```
$q = Company::findOrFail(1);
$q->update(['status' => 0]);
$q->delete();
```